# Is there a reason Ant-Man looks sad when the Asgardians are hailing the Avengers?

Tags: marvel, avengers, ant-man, avengers-earth-mightiest-heroes

At the end of the first season of [The Avengers: Earth's Mightiest Heroes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Avengers%3A_Earth%27s_Mightiest_Heroes) animated series, after Thor admitted to his father the real saviour of the Nine Realms was not him but actually are the Avengers, Odin decided to thank them:

During that sequence, we can see at 0:50 that Ant-Man (Hank Pym) does not look very happy:

[image: A close up on Hawkeye and Ant-Man as they are being acclaimed by the Asgardians. Although the former looks clearly happy about it, the latter seems depressed.]

Granted, Hulk does not look very impressed either, but Ant-Man looks genuinely sad. Is it ever explained why?

Comment: Could it be because the quality of animation seems to have *regressed* since the 1980s?

Comment: @Valorum Thanks for the chuckles.

Comment: I don't have facts and data to share. I always took the downcast expression to reflect Hank Pym had pretty much decided at this point to resign the superhero life, so this would be his last hurrah as an Avenger.  Also, the violence of the super life all had gotten him down.  The Asgardians are a warrior culture and they were generally cheering a damn good battle.